# I have an exercise in haskell and I need help correcting it

Tags: list, haskell

I have to define a function

```
   choose :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
    choose n ns = ...
```

which picks all occurrences of an integer `n` in a list. For example,

```
    choose 1 [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1] == [1, 1, 1]
    choose 1 [2, 3, 4, 6]       == []
```

---

I have already investigated how to filter a list and count the occurrences, only now what I want is for me to return a list with the repeated numbers
example:

```
   choose 1 [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1] == [1, 1, 1]
   choose 1 [2, 3, 4, 6] == []

   occurrences :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
   occurrences x = length. filter (x ==)
```

only that this code returns me the total of occurrences not a list with the numbers of occurrences

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question before?

Comment: haaam no, not this

Comment: In the interest of nudging you rather than simply solving, you might search for how one might filter a list in Haskell.

Comment: See [`filter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter). Also can you clarify your second example? `rep 2 [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1]` seems like it should return `[2]` not `[]`.

Comment: So in example 2 it must return [] because there is no number 1 that is repeated

Comment: What is the shortest list you can cook up where your `rep` gets the wrong answer? Try evaluating the function by hand on that list. Either you will get the same "wrong" answer as GHC, and will have a clue about where things went wrong, or you will mistakenly get the "right" answer. In the latter case, share with us how you think it will evaluate and we can point out your mistake.

Comment: I put another code that is closer to my problem

Comment: @NoRcKVR: If you don't care to understand how your code works, `choose = filter . (==)`.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with your template,

```
choose :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
choose n xs = ...
```

you want to start with pattern matching. You can match on `n` or on `xs`. Since `n` is just a number and we don't care which one it is, pattern matching on it will only give us the options `0`, `1`, `-2` and so on. Pattern matching on `xs` gives us two cases: Either the list is empty, or it has at least one element:

```
choose :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
choose n xs =
  case xs of
    [] -> ...
    x : rest -> ...
```

In the case of the empty list, `[]`, the interpretation is that you have to select a list of all the occurrences of `n` from the empty list. Since the empty list has no occurrences of `n`, an empty list of occurrences correctly describes the result:

```
choose :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
choose n xs =
  case xs of
    [] -> []
    x : rest -> ...
```

In the case of the non-empty list, `x : rest`, you have to think of the possible cases: Maybe `x` and `n` are the same number, in which case `x` should be part of the result. Maybe `x` and `n` are not the same number, in which case `x` should not be part of the result. In either case, `rest` are all the remaining numbers, some of which may have copies of `n`, too.

So in the case of the non-empty list, `x : rest`, you are actually doing three things:

1. Check if `x` should be part of the result:

   ```
   if n == x
   then ...
   else ...
   ```
2. Apply `choose n` recursively on `rest`:

   ```
   choose n rest
   ```
3. Combine the result of possibly adding `x` with the result of applying `choose n` recursively on `rest`.

   Here are two approaches and some thoughts on how to proceed with each one:

   ```
   (if n == x
    then ...
    else ...) ??? choose n rest
   ```

   or

   ```
   if n == x
   then ... ??? choose n rest
   else ... ??? choose n rest
   ```

Doing the combination can be a little tricky because of how the list constructor, `:` ("cons"), works.

For example, proceeding with approach 1 it may be tempting to write:

```
choose :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
choose n xs =
  case xs of
    [] -> []
    x : rest -> (if n == x
                 then x
                 else ???) : choose n rest
```

But what do you put in place of `???`? It has to be exactly one number, and it can't be any number. One quick way is to use `++` ("append") rather than `:` ("cons") since it accepts a list on both sides; then you can make the `(if ...)` return a list in both cases, either a list with one element in it, or a list with zero elements in it.

Proceeding with approach 2 you get:

```
choose :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
choose n xs =
  case xs of
    [] -> []
    x : rest -> if n == x
                then ... ??? choose n rest
                else ... ??? choose n rest
```

Here you don't have any trouble with using `:` under "`then ...`", since you can simply omit it in "`else ...`".

At this point, try and solve the exercise and provide a StackOverflow answer to your own question.

Comment: hooo ok thank you I will try, even though I am not very clear about the ???

Comment: That is because "???" consists of three question marks. It is supposedly not very clear. You have to do a bit of investigating and think what might be a meaningful list operator (e.g. `:` or `++`) that you can fit into the slot of "???". At some point you have to switch from asking for help to doing independent investigation, before you can switch back.